# Javascript Date Month Duration Calculate 1/1 to 31/1 returns 0

Tags: javascript, date

I searched a bit but couldnt find any similar post. Maybe I dont know how to search it.
 I m trying to calculate months but when the dates are from 1/1 to 31/1 it returns 0. I have thought of a solution but is there any other way?

Problematic Code.

```
    function monthDiff(d1, d2) {
    var months;
    months = (d2.getFullYear() - d1.getFullYear()) * 12;
    months -= d1.getMonth();
    months += d2.getMonth();
    return months <= 0 ? 0 : months;
}
```

Comment: What should you get then ? There is 0 months of difference between 1/1 and 31/1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A solution is to add a day to date2 so it will go to the next month.

```
function monthDiff(d1, d2) {
    var months;
    months = (d2.getFullYear() - d1.getFullYear()) * 12;
    d2.setDate(d2.getDate()+1);
    months -= d1.getMonth();
    months += d2.getMonth();
    return months <= 0 ? 0 : months;
}
```

Comment: In that example, yes. However, that would break if the dates were slightly different, say 1/1 - 30/1.

Answer (score 1):

It will return 0, because it is the same month. It will not return 1 unless there is a months difference.

January 1st is the same month as January 30th.